# What are the high level steps and limitations for unlocking & jailbreaking an original iPhone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, unlock

My daughter has an original iPhone, aka iPhone 2G.  It is currently unlocked and jailbroken, but that was all done about 2 years ago.  She wants the latest iTunes now, so I am revisiting what the procedure and limitations are for updating, unlocking, and jailbreaking.

I think the right high level steps are:

1. Backup everything we want to keep. I
   am pretty sure the phone gets wiped
   during the process.
2. Download iTunes
   current release and install it and
   let it do whatever it wants to
   update the phone.
3. Follow the
   instructions in the iClarified guide
   "How to Unlock/Jailbreak Your iPhone
   2G on OS 3.1.3 Using RedSn0w
   (Windows)" at
   http://iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=7436
   which calls for RedSn0w 0.9.4, BL
   3.9, BL 4.6, and iPhone1,1_3.1.3_7E18_Restore.ipsw
4. Re-install apps via iTunes.  Restore backed up personal data.

Is this basically correct or are there any other gotchas or limitations?

Are there better or more current guides than the iClarified guide?

The phone will be used on T-Mobile.

meta question:  what tag should be used for an original iPhone?

Comment: Nice to see I'm not the only one still doing this on an original iPhone!

Comment: Be careful - you generally can't upgrade or downgrade without making sure the break works with both the specific version of firmware / iOS level on the device before and after the break. You may want to be very fastidious about making sure of the firmware levels before you upgrade / reload the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct on all points.  It's pretty straightforward following the points you listed above.

Comment: Yeah I just had nothing to add.